# Change saturation on Elemtary OS Loki

Tags: graphic-drivers, color-format

Before anything I would like to apologize for any typo, English isnt my first language.

Im using a system who is based on Ubuntu 16.04 (elementary OS Loki), before that I was using Ubuntu 14.04 that had support for AMD fglrx (removed on 16.04) consequently I could use the AMD Catalyst Control where I could increase the saturation of the monitor, thats a configuration that ive be using since I was a Windows user, and I really get used to the look that the increase saturation gives, its being really hard to adapt to the system without the saturation increase. Theres any software, driver or configuration where I can change the saturation ?

Comment: I've used the method mentioned (system settings > color) and never had any luck. The color saturation never changes.

Answer (score 1):

It includes both using System Settings > Color and the settings built into your monitor. Go to

System Settings > Color: Click your monitor and then click "View Details" it should ask you to install something. Change the profile then click view details and look at the preview tabs. keep doing this until you find the right one for you

After to get an added color boost play with you monitor settings to make it perfect.